# create a unique constraint over multiple tables

Tags: sql-server, unique-constraint

I am creating a database where we want to combine data of several sites into one database. I now have an issue with the unique constraint for the samplepoint table. for each site the samplepointname must be unique. in the old system I enforced this with a unique constraint. The problem in the new system is that the siteID's are not stored in te table with samplepoints because these are enheritted from the parent of samplepoints (projects).
can I create a unique constraint that include the siteID stored in its parent, or should I create a siteID field in the table itself

Comment: Create a SiteID column in the table itself.

Comment: Perhaps an indexed view with a unique constraint? Please show full schemas for all relevant tables

Comment: _these are enheritted from the parent of samplepoints_ Post DDL. How is "inheritance" defined within your schema?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused by some of the phrasing of the question, so I'm going to lay out some clarifying assumptions based on what I think is my best read of it. Hopefully these assumptions actually match your situation.

In the original configuration, you had:

- a single site
- represented by a single pair of tables named "project" and "samplepoints"
- a unique constraint over a field named "samplepointname"
- a field named "siteID" in in a table named "project"
- it had previously been unnecessary to add "siteID" to "samplepoints" because there was only one row in "project" and that one row's single "siteID" was always implied throughout the table "samplepoints"

And in the new configuration you have the following changes:

- multiple sites
- one row for each site in the table "projects"
- a unique value for each field "siteID" in "projects"

You've stated that the field "sitepointname" within each site must be unique, but not globally. So I'm going to work with that.

Given these assumptions, you almost certainly will not merely want but *need to* add "siteID" to your table "sitepoints". This is because you can no longer simply read from "projects" and "sitepoints" at the same time without either joining them or adding a WHERE clause to filter down to the relevant site.

In fact, if your table "sitepoints" has already been populated without "siteID" you may well need to obtain the original tables from all of the different sites, empty that consolidated table, and repopulate it such that "siteID" correctly represents each independent site.

After you've added the new field "siteID", you'll remove the UNIQUE constraint on the field. You're going to replace that with what you'll use instead, and if you don't remove it all names will need to be unique across *all sites* rather than just within each site.

If you're simply executing commands directly, this will create that index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX unique_sitepointnames ON sitepoints (siteID, sitepointname);
```

The index name "unique_sitepointnames" is just an identifier, it can be whatever you wish, but that's my suggestion for it as it's clear and describes the purpose.

Rather than "UNIQUE" being a constraint on the column, "UNIQUE" is here a constraint on the index. Any more options to how the index is created is just optimization.

Comment: Hi Talia, thanks for your explanation. your assumptions are indeed correct. and I believe adding the field site ID to the table with samplepoints as well is the easiest option. thanks